# how to return data through function when fetching data from firebase realtime-database in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get this key in DATA and use this key outside of the function?

```
let DATA = [];

  const database = admin.database();
  let keyref = database.ref("data");

  keyref.once("value", async function (snapshot) {
    let key = await snapshot.val(); // i want this key data out side this function
    DATA.push(key);
    console.log(DATA);
  });

 console.log(DATA); // i want here that inside function key
```

In short, I want fetched data outside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fetching RTDB data only once, it is advised to use the `get()` method. This method is asynchronous, so you need to do something along the following lines:

```
  async function getRTDBData(ref) {
    const database = admin.database();
    const keyref = database.ref(ref);
    const snapshot = await keyref.get();

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        return snapshot.val();
    } else {
       return .... // Up to you to adapt here
    }
  }

  getRTDBData("data")
  .then(val => {
      // Do what you want with val
      console.log(val);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Renaud Ternec, You made my day Love you Brother...

Comment: Sir, how do I store this `snapshot.val()` out of function as I want to store that value globally. after store globally I want to use in getRTDBData.

Comment: You can only do that in the `then` block, because the function is asynchronous.

Comment: Ok Sir let me try something

Comment: More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Sir, In a simple way I want to store these fetched data in a variable and I want to use it for one hour it is possible after one hour again I call firebase real-time database and update my variable. Working on your given function, Expedient?

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function getData() {
  console.log("Refreshing Firebase Credentials");
  const keyref = database.ref("data");
  const snapshot = await keyref.get();

  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    const snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
    console.log(snapshotVal);
    credentials = {
      expires_at: new Date(snapshotVal.expires_at),
      enc_key: snapshotVal.enc_key,
      iv: snapshotVal.iv,
    };
  } else {
    console.log("Firebase Credentials not found");
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getData
};
```

Use this function where you want to this data